# Getting Dynamic Data Attributes

Tags: jquery

I have searched for this and found answers very similar to what I'm looking for but not quite. As a definite non-expert maybe I didn't know exactly how to search or what to search for. If this is a duplicate I'm sorry.

The main page has three bootstrap modals, each fired from three different buttons. Each modal asks the visitor to choose different options to put on their product for their order. When they select an option, it closes the modal and updates the main window to show the price for that option in their total price, and it removes the button to launch that modal (since it's already configured).

Most of that is working except for the updating the total price component. I can get only one of the three to work at a time. If you select any option (1, 2, or 3) it will update the price correctly, but neither of the other two options will update the total price. I presume the reason is in how I'm reading and setting the data attributes, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
First Option Modal Window

<div id="addFirstOption" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add First Option</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Please choose the first option</p>
            <div id="dCalc">
            <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
                <input type='submit' name='name1' value='159.95' id='1' />
            <input type='submit' name='name2' value='169.95' id='2'/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Second Option Modal Window

<div id="addSecondOption" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Second Option</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Please choose the second option</p>
            <div id="dCalc">
            <form name="secondOptionForm" id="secondOptionForm">
                <input type='submit' name='name1' value='10.00' id='1' />
            <input type='submit' name='name2' value='15.00' id='2'/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Third Option Modal Window
<div id="addThirdOption" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Third Option</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Please choose third option</p>
            <div id="dCalc">
            <form name="thirdOptionForm" id="thirdOptionForm">
                <input type='submit' name='name1' value='212.95' id='1' />
            <input type='submit' name='name2' value='289.95' id='2'/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Main Page JQuery Code

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-id="addFirstOption"]').data("firstPrice", 0.00);
    $('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').data("secondPrice", 0.00);
    $('[data-id="addThirdOption"]').data("thirdPrice", 0.00);
    $('[data-id="totalprice"]').data("price", 549.95); // this price set dynamically in PHP
});

$( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false
    });

    $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
    lightbox.option({
      'showImageNumberLabel': false
    })
    $(".addToBuildButton").click(function(){
        $("#addFirstOption").modal("show");
    });
    $(".addToBuildSecondOption").click(function(){
        $("#addSecondOption").modal("show");
    });
    $(".addToBuildThirdOption").click(function(){
        $("#addThirdOption").modal("show");
    });

$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[data-id="addFirstOption"]').append($(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    $('[data-id="addFirstOption"]').data("firstPrice", $(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    sum += parseFloat($('[data-id="addFirstOption"]').data("firstPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="totalprice"]').data("price")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').data("secondPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addThirdPrice"]').data("thirdPrice"));
    $(".showFinalPrice").replaceWith("$"+sum.toFixed(2));

    $( "#addFirstOptionElement" ).empty();
    $('#addFirstOption').modal('toggle');
});

$("#secondOptionForm").submit(function(x) {
    var sum = 0;
    x.preventDefault();
    $('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').append($(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    $('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').data("secondPrice", $(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    sum = parseFloat($('[data-id="firstOption"]').data("addFirstPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="totalprice"]').data("price")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').data("secondPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addThirdOption"]').data("thirdPrice"));
    $(".showFinalPrice").replaceWith("$"+sum.toFixed(2));

    $( "#addSecondOptionElement" ).empty();
    $('#addSecondOptional').modal('toggle');
});

$("#thirdOptionForm").submit(function(y) {
    var sum = 0;
    y.preventDefault();
    $('[data-id="addThirdOption"]').append($(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    $('[data-id="addThirdOption"]').data("thirdPrice", $(document.activeElement).attr('value'));
    sum = parseFloat($('[data-id="firstOption"]').data("addFirstPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="totalprice"]').data("price")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addSecondOption"]').data("secondPrice")) + parseFloat($('[data-id="addThirdOption"]').data("thirdPrice"));
    $(".showFinalPrice").replaceWith("$"+sum.toFixed(2));

    $( "#addSThirdOptionElement" ).empty();
    $('#addControlModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

It visually adds the price options to the main screen from whichever option is selected first, but after that it only visually adds the prices to the main screen and won't update the running total held in the "totalprice" data element.

Am I going about this in a wacky way? What am I missing? Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my error! I was using replaceWith() which was only working once (as you would expect, now that I have re-read JQuery's documentation on the replaceWith() function). I swapped that with html() and it works perfectly.